# How to fix Minecraft showing as a grey question mark on the Launcher?

Tags: launcher, icons, minecraft

When I play Minecraft, the icon in the Unity Launcher for it is always a grey question mark. This has persisted from Minecraft 1.6.2 to 1.7.4.

See this screenshot:

[image: Icon]

How can this be fixed?

---

I have tried to create a .desktop file to launch the Minecraft launcher, however this  only gives the launcher an icon and the game still shows as a grey question mark.

The .desktop file attempted was (adapted from [this asnwer](https://askubuntu.com/a/263581/176889)):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Minecraft TEST
Comment=
Exec=java -jar /opt/Minecraft/Minecraft_launcher.jar
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Minecraft_Block.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

I've also tried creating a file with `gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new` however that doesn't work either.

With either method, if I specify an icon in the .desktop file, the icon is given to the Minecraft launcher, not the game (I want the game to have an icon as well).

---

I was using Ubuntu 13.04; I've since upgraded (via a fresh install) to 13.10 with the same issue persisting.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty impossible problem to solve, unless you want to rewrite some Java code.

Unless Mojang and/or Java wants to re-program Minecraft to add an icon, it is not going to happen.

Try to contact Mojang to put an icon. If you are willing to muck through craptons of code, you might do it yourself, but I am not writing a 30-page long article for this. Sorry for that problem. Maybe tweet `@Jeb_`?

Answer (score 1):

This should answer a couple of questions:

[[MC-30900] Minecraft window does not set WM class, name, role, or title properties on X11/Linux - JIRA](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-30900)

Answer (score 0):

These guys are over-thinking this a little too hard.
The solution is simple, redirect your .svg

> Icon=/usr/share/icons/Minecraft_Block.svg

to a .ico file (Icon File) so it would look something like this:

> Icon=/usr/share/icons/Minecraft_Block.ico

A quick way is to go [here](http://convertico.com/) and use the url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGCXb.png a simply click the big 'GO' button

EDIT: Sorry I know this is an old question but it was the first when I searched how to do this. Now you have a Correct answer :P

Comment: Nope, that's not it, the launcher could have an icon, since his own launcher has an icon. Probably a case of `StartupWMClass`, but like you said, the question is too old to find out for sure.